# How to play 360º video in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, video, 360-degrees

Before downvote please read the question, I also see other question but doesn't find useful.

I have a requirement in my current app, where i needed to play 360º video (Like Panorama). one app on app store doing same Name "GoPano"

http://itunes.apple.com/ke/app/gopano/id459463884?mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is embeded player of GoPano. what they done is play video from Java script and with flex.

Comment: Do you mean to say www.panframe.com are using goPano video player ?

Comment: No my mean to say this app uses http://itunes.apple.com/ke/app/gopano/id459463884?mt=8.

Answer (score 16):

I created a framework over the last 2.5 years, which plays back 360° panoramic video playback on iOS, similar to your requirements. 
It is compatible with versions 4.3 up to 6.x at this point.

You can download it at [www.panframe.com](http://www.panframe.com) and try if this is what you are looking for.

The framework supplies a UIView that you can easily add as a child and an asset class which you can connect to the view and which will take care of playing spherical panoramic content.
You can look at the [interface](http://www.panframe.com/sdk/ios/api/1.8/index.html) I used.

You can use it like this dynamically for example in your UIViewController at runtime:

```
    // initialize an PFView
    PFView pfView = [PFObjectFactory viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    pfView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    // set the appropriate navigation mode PFView
    [pfView setNavigationMode:PF_NAVIGATION_MOTION];

    // add the view to the current stack of views
    [self.view addSubview:pfView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:pfView];
```

And when you want to play an 360 video asset (from a file URL) you implement the following:

```
    PFView pfAsset = [PFObjectFactory assetFromUrl:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] observer:(PFAssetObserver*)self];

    if ([pfAsset getStatus] != PF_ASSET_ERROR)
    {
        [pfView displayAsset:pfAsset];
        [pfAsset play];
    }
```

**Update**:
In case some one wants to use it in cordova apps, you can find plugin [here](https://github.com/jumpbytehq/cordova-jb-plugin-panframe)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @Ron Bakker can you please give suggestion for continue play video with their state in the panframe demo?

Answer (score 9):

I found these repos useful when creating my own video 360° player:

- https://github.com/hanton/HTY360Player
- https://github.com/Aralekk/simple360player_iOS
- https://github.com/nomtek/spherical_video_player_ios

---

The last one is mine, and [here](https://www.nomtek.com/video-360-in-opengl-ios-part-1-3d-scene/) is it's description.

Comment: I put together another pretty basic SceneKit implementation which can be found here: https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ThreeSixtyPlayer

Answer (score 1):

Google recently released the CardboardSDK for IOS, which supports 360 video playing.

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ios/